# classes of same name in swagger maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, swagger

I hope some of you do use the swagger maven plugin by kongchen.
I have been struggling a bit on an issue. In fact I have two classes with the same but from different packages. In the generated swagger.json file there is only one of them mentioned.
Let's say I have com.test.swagger.param.Foo and com.test.swagger.response.Foo.
In swagger.json only com.test.swagger.param.Foo is available.
As a side effect the generated html documentation is not accurated. 
Is there a way to force the plugin to take the class packages into account?

Best regards

Comment: Did you get further with this? I am having the exact same problem, and if you found out more, please add an answer here:)